# AWS ACM two certificates with same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, record, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I created a first certificate in AWS ACM like *.dev.mydomain.com then I created the records in Route 53 and it worked.

Now i'm trying to create a new certificate with the domain *.dev.mydomain.com and an additional name like *.myapp.dev.mydomain.com
I have added the records in Route 53 but it's in pending validation state for more than 24hours now so i guess there is a problem

So in the end i should two certificate for the same domain just one of them have an additional name

Do you know if what i'm trying to do is possible ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In general, you can have up to 100 names in a certificate. However, your question lacks details, so we can only guess what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who is trying to do this it's possible and it is working.

The certificate was in pending validation for another reason.

Thank you

Comment: what was the reason for the pending validation?